# Upgrade gcc compiler / other fix for backward compatible

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation, arm

For a project I need to upgrade application on older hardware, but the used kernel version is very old. and compiling the current application is a pain.

The whole picture, for a project we used x86 board with a 2.6.32 kernel.(Debian)
compiling the application with gcc 4.4.5.
Years later we swapped the cpu's for ARM7 and new kernel 3.0.35 (buildroot)
Using linaro-arm-linux-2013.01.(gcc version 4.7.3 20130102)

The main problem is that the code is now based on GCC 4.7.3 and is more C11 then with gcc 4.4.5.
Local compile is not an option as my machine is x64 and the target is x86. One of the packages used is GTK2, and this is not supported in the x86/x64 build method.
The code for the x86 board is now compiled on an older virtual machine.

How can I overcome this problem without rewriting the program to keep the older gcc 4.4.5. happy?

Upgrading the x86 board is not an option as I do not get time to develop and test this.

Comment: If you are willing to dedicate some time, you could make a 4.7.3 'cross compiler' with x64 host and x86 target.  The OS would be Linux 2.6.32 (minor tweak in libc).  When building a cross gcc, you can specifiy the glibc to keep the same deployed version.  Only code generation will change so the new cross **can** be made compatible with your deployed 4.4.5 base.  Otherwise, you need to modify your code to compile.

Comment: This sound like a plan , any suggestions where to look for making this cross compiler?

Comment: in this thread: http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/How-to-build-Kernel-2-6-x-td34762.html Thomas Petazzoni is discussing why an older kernel is not available.

Comment: That is 2.6.16, your 2.6.32 should be fine as it has menuconfig and knows about header_install.  You may have more luck with older versions of http://crosstool-ng.org/  It is also based on menuconfig.  See if the options are available for your kernel and deployed libc.  Using even older versions should be fine as linux/libc try to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Just checked and even the newest crosstool-ng is supporting 2.6.32.68 (patchlevel shouldn't matter but for security reasons you should be patching your boards) and glibc 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

try to compile hello.c with those linaro arm cross compiler:

see if ./a.out works or not.

gcc-4.x

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-4/

gcc-5.x

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5/

gcc-6.x

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

1.gcc-linaro-xxx-i686_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz

2.gcc-linaro-xxx-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem:

Got the buildroot files from this webpage: https://gist.github.com/icopitg-fh

Got the buildroot version 2013.11

Build the kernel + needed packages. Be aware that some like the libc will break due to the version of make. my version is 4 and the configure script does not not accept version found. This can be solved by changing the make. (change the regexp).